# Which one is appropriate to use? 'works' or 'worked'

Tags: tense

Which tense is appropriate to use 'works' or 'worked'? Please explain.

1.Leona works harder than any other lawyer in the firm.

2.Leona worked harder than any other lawyer in the firm

Comment: Appropriate for what?

Comment: Needs more context, both are syntactically correct, but for different use cases.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is that the past tense is used when talking about past events, and the present tense is used for speaking about the present.

> Leona works harder than any other lawyer in the firm.

This indicates that Leona *currently* works in the law firm and that it is your *current* opinion she works hard than any other lawyer.

The past tense is the most common tense for fiction, as it follows the natural tendency of retelling a story or events in a chronological way:

> Leona worked harder than any other lawyer in the law firm.

There are also situations where we default to using the past tense, for example, if you did not know that Leona *still* worked at the law firm:

> -"I remember Leona - she worked at that law firm."
>   -"Yes, and she still works there."